# Less decrement z-index from high to low value

Tags: html, css, less, z-index

I've found this `Less` loop to generate incremental values:

```
@iterations: 10;

.loopingClass (@index) when (@index > 0) {
    .item-panel:nth-child(@{index}) {
        position: relative;
        z-index: @index;
    }
    .loopingClass(@index - 1);
}
.loopingClass (@iterations);
```

But how can I turn the above so it generates decremental values? (i.e goes the other way round)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the value of `z-index` property as `@iterations - @index + 1` and as a side note, in order to prevent the repetition of `position: relative` in every pseudoclass, just move that property outside the loop

```
@iterations: 10;

.item-panel {
  position: relative;
}

.loopingClass (@index) when (@index > 0) {
    .item-panel:nth-child(@{index}) {
        z-index: @iterations - @index + 1;
    }
    .loopingClass(@index - 1);
}
.loopingClass (@iterations);
```

---

Compiled output

```
.item-panel {
  position: relative;
}

.item-panel:nth-child(10) {
  z-index: 1;
}
.item-panel:nth-child(9) {
  z-index: 2;
}

...

.item-panel:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad, this is my first attempt to use less :)